# Clues for genetic basis in Autism Spectrum Disorders

Tags: autism, genetics

In [Principles of Neural Science 5th edition](https://neurology.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookID=1049), Chapter 3, It Is said that Autism Is a genetic disorder but which genes are involved Is not clear, how do we know there Is a genetic basis and Is not a response to environmental factors (or a combination)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is autism caused by genetics?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/17284/is-autism-caused-by-genetics)

Answer (score 1):

There is a clear heritable component that seems to be "highly genetically heterogeneous and may be caused by both inheritable and de novo gene variations" [(Rylaarsdam, Gomboa, 2019)](https://doi.org/10.3389/fncel.2019.00385). There has been hundreds of genes implicated in autism and a complex interaction of non-heritable gene variations as well, "genetic modifiers such as copy number variation, single nucleotide polymorphisms, and epigenetic alterations likely play a key role" (Rylaarsdam, Gomboa, 2019).

The Rylaarsdam review article summarises the current state of play in terms of the genetic and non-heritable gene factors as well.

**Reference:**

Rylaarsdam, L., & Guemez Gamboa, A. D. (2019). Genetic Causes and Modifiers of Autism Spectrum Disorder. Frontiers in Cellular Neuroscience, 13, [385]. https://doi.org/10.3389/fncel.2019.00385